# How to get value from a dynamic link

Tags: php, regex

i have some dynamic link like this

```
<a href="names.php?action=names&amp;name=1">jehan</a> 
<a href="names.php?action=names&amp;name=2">roy</a>
```

I want to extract just jehan and roy from those links.I have tried this

```
preg_match_all("'(.*?)</a>'", $check, $match);
```

I have no idea how to do this properly :(

Comment: Your missing delimiters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
/<a [^>]+>(.*)<\/a>/
```

http://regexr.com/3abv0

There are more elegant ways to work this out. [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use to parse text from `HTML` links. Any further `HTML` parsing needs I had I would switch to a parsing library for `PHP`.

**Regex**

```
(?<=\>)\w+(?=\<\/a\>)
```

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/rK0gK4/1)

**Usage**

```
$re = "/(?<=\\>)\\w+(?=\\<\\/a\\>)/m"; 
$str = "<a href=\"names.php?action=names&amp;name=1\">jehan</a> \n<a href=\"names.php?action=names&amp;name=2\">roy</a>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a [^>]*>\K[^<]*(?=<\/a>)
```

You can try this to grab the links.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/3

```
$re = "/<a [^>]*>\\K[^<]*(?=<\\/a>)/m";
$str = "<a href=\"names.php?action=names&amp;name=1\">jehan</a> \n<a href=\"names.php?action=names&amp;name=2\">roy</a>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```